# Two infinitives in a row: "not to try to kiss her"

Tags: infinitives, redundancy

Can I use double infinitive in a sentence like in the second example below?

> My friend: "Try not to kiss her, Manny"
>
> Me: "Why are you telling me not "to try to kiss" her?"

Is the second sentence correct as it has two infinitives together?

Comment: It's correct, but your paraphrase of what your friend said means something different.  Your friend said "Make a big effort to not kiss her": this is an instruction to resist temptation. Your paraphrase means "Don't make any attempt to kiss her" this is an instruction not to do it.

Comment: So what you are saying is that what he tried to imply was you can kiss her but try not to

Comment: As the sentence stands it is ambiguous, he could be saying "Don't kiss her" or he could be saying "See if you can keep **yourself** from kissing her" or possibly even "See if you can keep **her** from kissing you", more context or intonation would be necessary for it to be less ambiguous. Implicitly it sounds like your friend knows you want to kiss her, otherwise he would have said "Don't kiss her".  "Do or do not, there is no try."

Comment: I concur he probably thought I whanted to kiss her since I most likely would but I wouldn't since she is his ex.

Answer (score -1):

There aren't two infinitives there. It seems like there is, but there is not.

The verb **try**, in this case, is *transitive* with *indirect object*.

**What does that mean???**

It means that the verb requires a complement, it does not stand by itself.

> -You've gotta try.
>
> -... try **what**?

---

When the complement is a noun or a pronoun, we can let the object of the sentence be direct:

> -You've gotta try the new rollercoaster!

When the object is direct we don't need prepositions to link the verb to the object.

But when the complement is an action, stated by another verb, we have two options:

1. Let the object be direct and use the suffix *-ing*;
2. Let the object be *indirect* and use a preposition.

In this case we have the second option:

> Why are you telling me not to try to kiss her?

There we have **"to"** linking the verbs together, but it's not an infinitive particle as it seems, it's a preposition required by the verb **try**.

In this case we could choose the first option with no damage to the meaning:

> Why are you telling me not to try kissing her?

---

The same case happens with the **"to"** before **try**. It's a preposition, required by the further away verb **"tell"**. This verb, in this context, is *transitive with direct and indirect object*. It means that it requires both types of object, *"me"*, which acts as direct object and *"(not) try to kiss her"*, which acts as the indirect object.

So there you have it, **zero** infinitives.

Comment: Is *to* before the infinitive called a preposition?

Comment: @V.V. no, it's not considered a preposition because it doesn't function as one. It is only an infinitive particle.

Comment: Then your explanation " it's. not an infinitive particle...it's a preposition required by the verb **try** " is not quite clear to me.

Comment: @V.V. you called my attention for something I hadn't noticed. Yes, the "to" before "try" is also a preposition, and I added this information to the answer.

Comment: @V.V. No, there are no prepositions in *to try to kiss*, just a pair of infinitive markers.